# Why does the body part of email is not found Python imap?

Tags: python-3.x, imap

Found an [article](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/reading-emails-in-python) about reading email with Python. The sender of the letter and the subject are found but there are problems with body of the mail - it is not found. Maybe there are some other ways to read body?

```
import imaplib
import email
from email.header import decode_header
import webbrowser
import os

# account credentials
username = "username@mail.ru"
password = "password"


def clean(text):
    return "".join(c if c.isalnum() else "_" for c in text)


imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.mail.ru")
imap.login(username, password)
# it is spam folder id
status, messages = imap.select("&BCEEPwQwBDw-")
messages = int(messages[0])

for i in range(messages, 0, -1):
    res, msg = imap.fetch(str(i), "(RFC822)")
    for response in msg:
        if isinstance(response, tuple):
            msg = email.message_from_bytes(response[1])
            subject, encoding = decode_header(msg["Subject"])[0]
            if isinstance(subject, bytes):
                subject = subject.decode(encoding)
            From, encoding = decode_header(msg.get("From"))[0]
            if isinstance(From, bytes):
                From = From.decode(encoding)
            print("Subject:", subject)
            print("From:", From)
            if msg.is_multipart():
                for part in msg.walk():
                    # extract content type of email
                    content_type = part.get_content_type()
                    content_disposition = str(part.get("Content-Disposition"))
                    try:
                        body = part.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
                    except:
                        pass
                    if content_type == "text/plain" and "attachment" not in content_disposition:
                        print(body)
                    elif "attachment" in content_disposition:
                        filename = part.get_filename()
                        if filename:
                            folder_name = clean(subject)
                            if not os.path.isdir(folder_name):
                                os.mkdir(folder_name)
                            filepath = os.path.join(folder_name, filename)
                            open(filepath, "wb").write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
            else:
                content_type = msg.get_content_type()
                body = msg.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
                if content_type == "text/plain":
                    print(body)
            if content_type == "text/html":
                folder_name = clean(subject)
                if not os.path.isdir(folder_name):
                    os.mkdir(folder_name)
                filename = "index.html"
                filepath = os.path.join(folder_name, filename)
                open(filepath, "w").write(body)
                webbrowser.open(filepath)
imap.close()
imap.logout()
```

For some reason, the body is not located and because of this, an error appears.

```
NameError: name 'body' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

`body` is not defined because of this:

```
try:
    body = part.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
except:
    pass
```

You tried to define body, but failed due to some kind of error that you allowed to pass silently (hint: don't do that!). Then the next blocks of code assumed that `body` had already been assigned when it hadn't.

Solution: define `body` *outside* of the `try/except` clause:

```
body = None
try:
    body = part.get_payload(decode=True).decode()
except:
    # pass
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exception()
    # this way you'll at least know what the error was
```

Comment: Oh, really, I forgot about this, thank you. But this doesn't change the question. Somehow the body is None and exception says: ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'```

Comment: @kfcgenius can you please edit your question and post the *full text* of the error and traceback?